# Group By - Total Hours and Hours by Category in Python / Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pandas-groupby

I need to calculate **Total Hours** and **Hours by Status** per Week using Python / Pandas **GROUP BY**.

```
Id             Week          Status Hours

1   01/10/2022 - 01/16/2022    On     5
2   01/10/2022 - 01/16/2022    Off    2
3   01/17/2022 - 01/23/2022    Off    6
4   01/17/2022 - 01/23/2022    On     1
5   01/17/2022 - 01/23/2022    On     5
6   01/03/2022 - 01/09/2022    On     10
7   01/10/2022 - 01/16/2022    Off    9
8   01/03/2022 - 01/09/2022    On     3
9   01/24/2022 - 01/30/2022    Off    4
10  01/24/2022 - 01/30/2022    On     7
```

```
test_data = {'Id': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10], 
             'Week': ['01/10/2022 - 01/16/2022', '01/10/2022 - 01/16/2022', '01/17/2022 - 01/23/2022', '01/17/2022 - 01/23/2022', '01/17/2022 - 01/23/2022', '01/03/2022 - 01/09/2022', '01/10/2022 - 01/16/2022', '01/03/2022 - 01/09/2022', '01/24/2022 - 01/30/2022', '01/24/2022 - 01/30/2022'], 
             'Status': ['On', 'Off', 'Off', 'On', 'On', 'On', 'Off', 'On', 'Off', 'On'], 
             'Hours': [5,2,6,1,5,10,9,3,4,7]}

test_df = pd.DataFrame(data=test_data)
```

I can get Total Hours by each Week:

```
test_df.groupby(by=['Week'], as_index=False).agg({"Hours": "sum"})
```

But I don't know how to also group by Status, so it will be 2 additional columns (**On Status Hours** and **Off Status Hours**)

If I add Status column just to the groupby part, it creates extra rows (I understand why)

```
test_df.groupby(by=['Week', 'Status'], as_index=False).agg({"Hours": "sum"})
```

Output I want:

| Week | Total Hours | On Status Hours | Off Status Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/03/2022 - 01/09/2022 | 13 | 13 | 0 |
| 01/10/2022 - 01/16/2022 | 16 | 5 | 11 |
| 01/17/2022 - 01/23/2022 | 12 | 6 | 6 |
| 01/24/2022 - 01/30/2022 | 11 | 7 | 4 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
(test_df
 .groupby(['Week', 'Status'])['Hours']
 .sum()
 .unstack(1, fill_value=0)
 .add_suffix(' Status Hours')
 .assign(**{'Total Hours': lambda d: d.sum(1)})
 )
```

Output:

```
Status                   Off Status Hours  On Status Hours  Total Hours
Week                                                                   
01/03/2022 - 01/09/2022                 0               13           13
01/10/2022 - 01/16/2022                11                5           16
01/17/2022 - 01/23/2022                 6                6           12
01/24/2022 - 01/30/2022                 4                7           11
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pd.pivot_table` to get your result:

```py
x = pd.pivot_table(
    test_df,
    index="Week",
    columns="Status",
    values="Hours",
    aggfunc="sum",
    fill_value=0,
).add_suffix(" Status Hours")
x["Total Hours"] = x.sum(axis=1)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
Status                   Off Status Hours  On Status Hours  Total Hours
Week                                                                   
01/03/2022 - 01/09/2022                 0               13           13
01/10/2022 - 01/16/2022                11                5           16
01/17/2022 - 01/23/2022                 6                6           12
01/24/2022 - 01/30/2022                 4                7           11
```